# How to generate a SAS token for Azure API (Api Management) in Java / Groovy?

Tags: java, azure, groovy, azure-api-management

I try to follow instructions [here (azure API reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/azure-api-management-rest-api-authentication#ProgrammaticallyCreateToken) to manage Azure API Management through their API.

Looks like that (groovy):

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder

import javax.crypto.Mac
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec

@Grab(group = 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module = 'httpclient', version = '4.5.2')

final def serviceName = 'my-api'
final def url = "https://${serviceName}.management.azure-api.net"
final String identifier = 'integration'
final byte[] primaryKey = Base64.decoder.decode('<key copy pasted from Azure web console > "API Management Service"')

final String expiry = '2018-03-01T12:26:00.0000000Z'

// SAS generation
def hmacSha256 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")
hmacSha256.init(new SecretKeySpec(primaryKey, "HmacSHA256"))
def toSign = "$identifier\n$expiry"
def signature = new String(Base64.encoder.encode(hmacSha256.doFinal(toSign.bytes)))
def sas = "SharedAccessSignature uid=${identifier}&ex=$expiry&sn=${signature}"

// URL Request
def getUsers = new HttpGet("$url/users?api-version=2017-03-01")
getUsers.setHeader('Authorization', sas)

def client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
def response = client.execute(getUsers)

println response
if (response.statusLine.statusCode == 200) {
    println "Users: " + new JsonSlurper().parse(response.entity.content)
} else {
    println "Error: ${response.entity.content.readLines()}"
}
```

Which result with:

```
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [Content-Length: 0, Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains, WWW-Authenticate: SharedAccessSignature realm="", error="invalid_token", error_description="User is not found or signature is invalid.", Date: Wed, 14 Feb 2018 14:33:14 GMT] [Content-Length: 0,Chunked: false]}
```

Note: when I'm using a manually generated API, it does work. The issue is on the signature generation.

Does anyone can give me some direction or working code sample (in Java)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those having same issue and are lucky enough to find this answer, 2 issues:

- signing algo is HmacSHA512, not HmacSHA256
- primaryKey is *not* to be Base64 decoded. Just use it as it.

Working code (groovy):

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder

import javax.crypto.Mac
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

@Grab(group = 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module = 'httpclient', version = '4.5.2')

final def serviceName = '<your service name>'
final def url = "https://${serviceName}.management.azure-api.net"
final String identifier = '<your identifier>'
final byte[] primaryKey = '<copy paste of primaryKey>'.bytes // do not base64 decode!!!

final String expiry = LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'0000Z'"))

// SAS generation
def hmacSha512 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA512")
hmacSha512.init(new SecretKeySpec(primaryKey, "HmacSHA512"))
def dataToSign = "$identifier\n$expiry"
def signature = new String(Base64.encoder.encode(hmacSha512.doFinal(dataToSign.bytes)))
def sas = "SharedAccessSignature uid=${identifier}&ex=$expiry&sn=${signature}"
println "SAS=$sas"

// URL Request
def getUsers = new HttpGet("$url/users?api-version=2017-03-01")
getUsers.setHeader('Authorization', sas)

def client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
def response = client.execute(getUsers)

println response
if (response.statusLine.statusCode == 200) {
    println "Users: " + new JsonSlurper().parse(response.entity.content)
} else {
    println "Error: ${response.entity.content.readLines()}"
}
```